# How can I get the last second of the last month as a default parameter value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to get the last second of the last month as a default value for a parameter. I can get the last day of the last month from this [query on social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/60dad686-f8c1-465a-8021-efa90f9a9003/how-to-get-the-previous-month-as-a-default-parameter-in-ssrs-2005?forum=sqlreportingservices)

> last month last day expression: `DateValue(DateAdd("D",-1,DateAdd("D",-(Day(Now)-1),Now)))`

The about would return 12am of the last day of the month. Starting with that I made one change so that I can get the last second of the last month.

```
=DateValue(DateAdd("S",-1,DateAdd("D",-(Day(Now)-1),Now)))
```

That does not work though as the time is still set to midnight.

How do I get the last second of the last month as a datetime value?

---

This has no affect on underlying queries that deal with report data. This is purely about showing an end user the start and end dates in a report header. "9/1/2018 00:00:00 to 9/30/2018 11:59:59"   "9/1/2018 00:00:00 to 10/1/2018 00:00:00". The former example to my end users is clearer that the data is in the month where as seeing number for the next month (like in the second example) is ... unsettling

Comment: I rubberducked the answer when I was trying to ask this question and had to type it out. I feel silly but figured I might as well share.

Comment: Why would you need the last second of the previous month for anything? Much better to say >= beginning of the month and < beginning of the next month. See [the section on `BETWEEN` here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/) and [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I do agree however as this value gets displayed in the report header the end users were having issues seeing the next month in a report that only displays data for last month. Its a visual thing for end users. I could also just drop the time but then they wonder if its midnight on the 30th or 11:59:59 of the 30th.

Comment: What if there is data on 11:59:59.9999999? Will they think *that* data is missing? If it's a report for February (or any range of days), why do you need to display time at all? I think your display is creating confusion unnecessarily.

Comment: If the data exists at that time it will still be included in the report as the query is looking for <= midnight of the first of the next month. This basically boils down to customer requirement. I did read through those linked articles which helped me understand some potential pitfalls but I don't think those apply here. if I didn't display time they would ask if that data for that last day is included. I might be able to refactor this just to show the month alone but if they ever change the range then that would not work

Comment: I know it will still be included in the report (well, I am trusting you that your query is correct in spite of the label). But if a user is confused about 11:59:59 they could also be confused about 11:59:59.9999999.

Comment: I do get your point and will have to see about addressing that. This report normally allows users to pick a date range. There is going to be a subscription that automatically picks values to represent last month. What ever I display has to account for both of those scenarios. Time is not a factor as users select dates. So while the presense of time might be odd it isnt currently for my end users. Yes, there would be a potential disconnect between the header and what is actually happeneing which could be bad. An extension of this question is UX of displaying these dates I suppose. another time

Comment: So is 11:59:59 in the dropdown too? I'm very confused about how this solves a problem on the output but doesn't address a problem on the input?

Comment: Sorry, I am not usually very good at explaining myself. I was mostly agreeing with you that I can be creating an issue where the details I am showing people does not accurately match the data as there is a potential for discrepancy. The input is not supposed to be an issue as users are just selecting calendar dates.

Comment: Right, but if they pick Feb 28th at the end date, shouldn't they already know what they intend (either for the report to end at midnight on Feb 28th, or include all of Feb 28th)? Slapping 11:59:59 on the label for the output seems too late to me.

Comment: You would hope so but I don't pretend to understand all end user requests especially when they are paying my company money to do things their way.

Comment: @AaronBertrand After a short discussion we are dropping the time from the display as they understand that the day mean all of that day (wish they told me that before). So now the result of this question does not matter to me anymore. Unless you feel that I am going to be misleading other professionals I can still leave the solution here .

Comment: Seems to me it's not even really a database question, except that your front-end code is formatting a date that came from the database (but didn't really, because the user selected it from a drop-down). UX is always an interesting discussion, I just don't know if it will be relevant to future readers here.

Comment: Indeed. Are those types of SSRS questions not in scope then? It still does involve database utilities but is definitely not an administration question. I really dont care either way but as long as it is not off topic then I should just be able to leave it stand. Only reason it is even here is just because I typed it all out.

Answer (score 1):

They key is the placement of `DateValue()` which:

> Returns a Date value containing the date information represented by a string, with the time information set to midnight (00:00:00).

The problem with where you are removing seconds is *inside* the `datevalue()` function which is dropping the time portion.

It is still important as you want time removed from the initial calculation for getting the last day of the month.

A little shifting around get the desired output.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Second,-1,DateValue(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-(Day(Now)-1),Now)))
```

or

```
=DateAdd("s",-1,DateValue(DateAdd("d",-(Day(Now)-1),Now)))
```